# Calculate days needed for the 4 workers to complete an 80 person-months job

Tags: connections

> The workload required to develop a system is estimated at 80
>   person-months if it is carried out by one person. When four staff
>   members with the same productivity work together to develop the
>   system, each member’s productivity is expected to decrease by 20%. How
>   many working days does it take for the four members to develop this
>   system? Here, this development work can be equally divided into four
>   parts, and the four members can perform each individual part in
>   parallel. In addition, each member can work 22 working days per month.

80 person-months is : $\cfrac{1}{80}$

So for the 4 of them we have : $0.8*t*\cfrac{4}{80} => t = \cfrac{80}{3.2} = 25$

And the result is : $ 25 * 22 = 550 $ days

But the correct result is **528**, what am I doing wrong here? Please show me, thanks alot!

Comment: @Stefanos: Yes: that’s the factor of $0.8$.

Comment: @Stefanos yes I have, I put 0.8 in the equation

Comment: The problem is very badly worded. I agree with your interpretation. Apparently what was intended, however, was that it would take a worker $20$% more time, not that he would work $80$% as fast. See the answer by Euler....IS_ALIVE.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott AWW.... I misread the question again, thanks alot!!!

Comment: No, I’d say that you read it correctly, but the author of the answer interpreted it poorly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each worker's productivity is cut by 20%, that means the total amount of work is $80 + .2*80 = 96$.  Thus, there are a total of $96*22/4 = 528$ working days.

Comment: That’s apparently the intended solution, but it’s not the way I would interpret the $20$% reduction in productivity or expect anyone else to interpret it. I agree with the OP’s interpretation: if one person working alone does $\frac1{80}$ of the job in one month, someone working at $80$% of that productivity does $0.8\cdot\frac1{80}=\frac1{100}$ of the job in one month. That is, in each month he does $20$% less work. On your interpretation it takes him $\frac{96}{80}=\frac65$ as long to do the job, so he works only $5/6$ as productively and therefore loses $16\frac23$% of his productivity.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Agreed.  Time to send a letter to the author.

Comment: Thanks alot! I misread the question! Again :(!